Meaning of the dimension of a family of higher genus curves on LMFDB
Among the data given in the LMFDB for certain higher genus curves is the "dimension", which is defined as follows: "Given a group of automorphisms $G$ acting on a curve $X/\mathbb{C}$ of genus $g$, with signature $[g_0;m_1, \ldots, m_r]$, the dimension of the family of curves with this signature is $3g_0+r-3$, where $r$ is the number of branch points of the map $X \to X/G$ and $g_0$ is the quotient genus."
https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/curve.highergenus.aut.dimension?timestamp=1619781982456742
The definition to me seems "combinatorial", depending on counting the branch points and combining that with the quotient genus (which is easy using Riemann-Hurwitz). My question is whether it has a deeper algebro-geometric meaning? For instance, is it an actual dimension of some natural vector space attached to the family of curves?

Surely it is the dimension of the moduli space, not the dimension of some associated vector space.

Welcome new contributor.  In characteristic zero, using the Riemann existence theorem, that equals the dimension of $H^1(X,T_X)^G$, which also equals the (local) dimension (at the moduli point of $X$) of the moduli space of smooth, projective curves that contain $G$ in their automorphism group.  In positive characteristic, this is much more subtle, cf. the Oort conjecture.

Thanks a lot for the clarification @JasonStarr
